# Radius of a circle drawn inside a quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be quadrilateral with area 18, with side AB parallel to the side CD and AB = 2CD. Let AD
be perpendicular to AB and CD. If a circle is drawn inside the quadrilateral ABCD touching all the
sides, then find its radius. Can someone provide me some hint.

Comment: What can you say about a circle which touches two parallel lines? How can you relate the information you have about the sides to what you know about the area of the quadrilateral?

Comment: Is the diameter of the circle is distance between the parallel lines ?

Comment: @Gold Yes, of course. And its not much of a work to prove it as well.

Comment: And then I think you can use the trapezoid area formula, manipulate it to get an equation.

Answer (score 1):

hint: consider the tangent point on four sides, $E,F,G,H$, $BE=BF,CF=CG$, and $BC=BF+FC=\sqrt{AB^2+AD^2}$,then what about $H$,can you go ahead?